# Proving $P(A\cap B^{\complement}) \leq P(A\cap C^{\complement}) + P(C\cap B^{\complement})$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to prove the inequality
\begin{equation*}
P(A\cap B^{\complement}) \leq P(A\cap C^{\complement}) + P(C\cap B^{\complement}),
\end{equation*}
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not necessarily independent. So far I have attempted to use
\begin{alignat*}{1}
P(A\cap B^{\complement}) &\leq P(A) + P(B^{\complement}),\\
P(A\cap C^{\complement}) &= P(A)+P(C^{\complement}) - P(A\cup C^{\complement}),\\
P(C\cap B^{\complement}) &= P(C)+P(B^{\complement}) - P(C\cap B^{\complement})
\end{alignat*}
by adding the 2nd and 3rd equations and then comparing the result to the RHS of the second inequality shown above. However, this did not appear to be helpful. I have also attempted to use indicator functions. With indicator functions I have tried using
\begin{equation*}
\chi_{A\setminus B} = \chi_{A}(1-\chi_{B}) \geq \chi_{A}-\chi_{B},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\chi_{A\setminus C} + \chi_{C\setminus B} = \chi_{A\cup C}+\chi_{C\cap B},
\end{equation*}
but this has not provided me with much insight on how to proceed.

From another question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3559437/887187)), I had the idea of possibly attempting to use
\begin{equation*}
1\geq \chi_{A\setminus B}\geq 0,\quad 1\geq \chi_{A}-\chi_{B} \geq -1 
\end{equation*}
while
\begin{equation*}
2\geq \chi_{A\cup B} + \chi_{C\cap B}\geq 0,
\end{equation*}
however I am unsure if these are valid statements as I am not very familiar with all of the arithmetic of indicator functions; and if it is valid, there is still the question of when $\chi_{A}-\chi_{B} \in [0,1]$. Can anyone provide guidance on what should be used here?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hint: For any measurable $E,F$ it holds that $P(E) = P(E \cap F) + P(E \cap F^c)$ (why?). Also as a result, $P(E) \ge P(E\cap F)$ (why?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean approach to consider starts by using
$$A = (A \cap C) \cup (A \cap C^c)$$
and this is actually a disjoint union since $C$ and $C^c$ are disjoint and $A\cap C \subset C$ and $A \cap C^c \subset C^c$. Following this idea, you can write
$$A \cap B^c = [(A \cap C) \cup (A \cap C^c)] \cap B^c = (A \cap B^c \cap C) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C^c)$$
where I will leave it to you to justify each of these equalities. You can also check that
$$
(A \cap B^c \cap C) \cap (A \cap B^c \cap C^c) = \varnothing
$$
so that
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^c) = \mathbb{P}((A \cap B^c \cap C) \cup (A \cap B^c \cap C^c)) 
    = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^c \cap C) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^c \cap C^c) 
\end{align*}
I will also leave it to you to conclude from this point.

Comment: Similar response to @Feng, but since your response provides slightly more detail I have accepted it as the answer. Thanks, it is super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B^{\complement})&=P(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C)+P(A\cap B^{\complement}\cap C^\complement)\\
&\leq P(B^{\complement}\cap C)+P(A\cap C^\complement).
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, it is clear to me now. Thanks! :)